# I use data transfer via bundle, but for some reason the data is transmitted only 1 time

Tags: java, android, bundle

I use this piece of code to send data

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    DialogFragment dlg;
    dlg = new barcodeView();
    Coupons coupons = coupons2.get(position);
    String i = coupons.getTAG();

    Log.v("dwdwdw",""+i);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount500")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "5000112592702");

        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount300")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054490086");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount100")){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054491472");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount500")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054492387");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount300")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0049000065206");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount100")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "050051000481");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
```

And such for obtaining `barcode_data = bundle.getString("someValue");`

But why the first time all is well, the data is sent, but with the next click displays the old data, that is, the data sent does not change. How to clean them?
I checked Debug mode and realized that `Coupons coupons = coupons 2.get(position);` not changed. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

All Recycler Adapter from where I send data:

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Coupons> coupons2;
 RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Coupons> coupons2){

    this.coupons2 = coupons2;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;










}


@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupon,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
 private int position;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Coupons coupons = coupons2.get(position);
    this.position = position;

    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(coupons.getLogo());
    viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(this);





}
Coupons coupons;

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return coupons2.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    DialogFragment dlg;
    dlg = new barcodeView();
    if (coupons!=null){
        coupons = null;
    }

    Coupons coupons = coupons2.get(position);


    String i = coupons.getTAG();

    Log.v("dwdwdw",""+i);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount500")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "5000112592702");

        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount300")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054490086");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("lentaAmount100")){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054491472");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount500")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0000054492387");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount300")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "0049000065206");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
    if (i.equals("petiarochkaAmount100")){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        bundle.clear();
        bundle.putString("someValue", "050051000481");
        dlg.setArguments(bundle);
        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");

    }


}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    final ImageView imageView;

    ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    }
}
```

All DialogFragment where I get data:

```
 public class barcodeView extends DialogFragment implements 
View.OnClickListener {

ImageView barcodeview;
TextView barcodetextView;
String barcode_data;
// barcode image
Bitmap bitmap = null;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setTitle("Ваш штрихкод");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.barcode_view, null);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    barcode_data = bundle.getString("someValue");
    barcodetextView = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewbarcode);
    barcodeview =  v.findViewById(R.id.barcodeView);

    try {
        bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300);
        barcodeview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        barcodetextView.setText(barcode_data);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return v;

}
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}

private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
    // Very crude at the moment
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
        if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
            return "UTF-8";
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
   barcodeview = null;
   barcodetextView = null;
   barcode_data = null;
   Log.v("dwdw","wdwdwd");


}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to use `private int position;` to get `position` in `onClick`

Let try to implement `OnClickListener` follows below code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final Coupons coupons = coupons2.get(position);

    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(coupons.getLogo());
    viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO: you can use 'coupons' and 'position' declared as final here
            String i = coupons.getTAG();
        }
    });
}
```